# why newly brought acera plam is turning yellow and corner of leaf is becoming wilt?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, watering, palm

[image: whole plant][image: leaf corners]I brought acera plam three days back and placed it indoor near window, by which the plant gets sunlight after 1 pm. When i brought the plant the soil was just watered so I thought watering after a week would be fine and so I didnt water the plant for three days. Now the acera palm leaf is turning yellow and corner of leaf is becoming dry like wilt. so what im i supposed to do now.

Note: (aaded information) The pot was changed by the seller at the time of purchasing from plastic black bag to pot and added more soil to fill the pot. 
Pic: Corner leaf
[image: Corner leaf]